# Django filter queryset of a models that are related with a foreign key to other model?

Tags: django, join, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have a simple question.
I have two models(Waiter and Manager) and they both contains same foreign key to restaurant as:

```
class Managers(BaseUser):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurants, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Waiters(BaseUser):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurants, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And restaurant model:

```
class Restaurants(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating = models.DecimalField(null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
```

So I need to get all waiters that restaurant=managers__restaurant_id.

I think in SQL would be:

```
select *
From Waiters w
Left outer join Managers m
On w.restaurant_id = m.restaurant_id
```

Note*
I'm able to query that like below:

```
manager = Managers.objects.filter(id=request.usr.id)
queryset=Waiters.objects.filter(restaurant=manager.restaurant_id)
```

But is there any way that i could do it in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is there any way that i could do it in one query.

This is in one query, but it will work with a subquery is probably not that efficient.

You can however filter in a more compact way with:

```
Waiters.objects.filter(restaurant__managers=request.user.id)
```

We can look "through" relations by using double underscores (`__`). Here we thus are looking for `Waiters` objects for which it restaurant is related to a `Managers` object with the given id of `request.user.id`.

Comment: just wow! 
I have been stuck here for a week and i could not figure it out.
But can you please explain how that worked because I'm not quite understanding.

Comment: I was working on this and figured it out  that if i have a different manager that belongs to same restaurant this wont work:
```Waiters.objects.filter(restaurant__managers=request.user.id)
```
Since  we are looking for the request id of a current user does this mean that i need to go back into this:
```manager = Managers.objects.filter(id=request.usr.id)
queryset=Waiters.objects.filter(restaurant=manager.restaurant_id)
```
or is there any  way  that i  could filter directly the waiters and managers  that  belong to same restaurant im a bit confused.

Comment: @AstritMaliku: but a `Manager` only refers to one `Restaurant`, if the same user has multiple related `Manager`s, it will list all `Waiters` that work at a restaurant managed by the user, so we can retrieve waiters of multiple restaurants if the `request.user` manages these restaurants.

Comment: @AstritMaliku: can you edit the question with sample data where it does not return the expected queryset?

Comment: I was doing something similar to get the related objects  in another model and I thought request.user works only  for that specific user but, as you mentioned ```if the same user has multiple related Managers, it will list all Waiters```.
So the problem was in my relation not in query.
All good,thank you.
I will delete my question in comment because there is no need for it.
@Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 1):

how about this??

```
queryset = Managers.objects.filter(id=request.usr.id and Waiters.objects.filter(restaurant=manager.restaurant_id))
```

Comment: It works of course but I'm not quite sure about performance that's why I was looking for a better solution.
And I think @ Willem Van Onsem answer was right.